# Using auto-layout to create an aligned form

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, swift5

I'm looking to create an aligned-form input screen in a Swift5 iOS app, looking something like

```
╔══════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╗
║ Name         ║ [         text field        ] ║
║ Phone number ║ [         text field        ] ║
║ Fax number   ║ [         text field        ] ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╝
```

(sans the lines) such that the labels and fields scale reasonably for different screen sizes. I know I can use horizontal stackviews inside a vertical stackview, but to get the text fields aligned I'd either have to give the label a fixed size, or a the horizontal stackviews a fixed proportion. Are better options available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use stack views. Instead, use plain constraints:

1. constrain the text fields left, right, and vertical spacing - to each other (or safe area).
2. constrain each label baseline to each text field.
3. Constrain the labels left - to the safe area.
4. Constrain each label right to each text filed, using >= relation.